# Apostol Analysis Book Theorem 1.6

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I've currently hit a roadblock in understanding **Theorem 1.6** from Apostol:

> Every pair of integers $a$ and $b$ has a common divisor $d$ of the form $d = ax + by$ where $x$ and $y$ are integers. Moreover, every common divisor of $a$ and $b$ divides this $d$.

> **Proof**
>
> First assume that $a \geq 0, b\geq 0$ and use induction on $n=a+b.$
>
> If $n=0$ then $a=b=0,$ and we can take $d=0$ with $x=y=0.$
>
> Assume then that the theorem has been proved for $0,1,2,3,4,\ldots, n-1.$
>
> By symmetry we can assume $a\geq b.$
>
> If $b=0$ take $d=a,x=1,y=0.$
>
> If $b \geq 1$ we can apply the induction hypothesis to $a-b$ and $b,$ since their sum is $a = n-b \leq n-1.$
>
> Hence there is a common divisor $d$ of $a-b$ and $b$ of the form $d = (a-b)x + by.$
>
> This $d$ also divides $(a-b) + b = a,$ so $d$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$ and we have $d = ax + (y-x)b,$ a linear combination of $a$ and $b.$
>
> To complete the proof we need to show that every common divisor divides $d.$ Since a common divisor divides $a$ and $b,$ it also divides the linear combination $ax+(y-x)b = d.$
>
> This completes the proof if $a\geq 0$ and $b\geq 0.$

There are a multitude of questions that have crept up on me and i will ask them to the best of my capabilities.

1. First assume that a ≥ 0, b ≥ 0 and use induction on n=a+b. If n=0 then a=b=0, and we can take d=0 with x=y=0. Assume then that the theorem has been proved for 0,1,2,3,4,....n-1.

Since d=ax+by, and n=a+b and both a and b are  ≥ 0, we can deduce a=b=0. What is the benefit of assuming that the theorem has been proved for 0,1,2,3,4,....n-1.?

2. By symmetry we can assume a≥b.

How are we using symmetry on this situation

3. If b=0 take d=a,x=1,y=0.

This maybe because in d=ax+by, when b=0,x=1, y=0 the equation comes down to d=a

4. If b ≥ 1 we can apply the induction hypothesis to a-b and b, since their sum is a= n-b ≤ n-1.Hence there is a common Divisor d of a-b and b of the form d = (a-b)x + by.

Couldn't clearly understand the above.

5. This d also divides (a-b) + b = a, so d is a common divisor of a and b and we have d = ax + (y-x)b, a linear combination of a and b.To complete the proof we need to show that every common divisor divides d. Since a common divisor divides a and b, it also divides the linear combination ax+(y-x)b = d.This completes the proof if a≥0 and b≥0.

Need some clarification on the above.

I would like to apologize for the long winded question, but any help on deciphering the above theorem would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Please use MathJax (with "$" delimiters) rather than code blocks (with "```" delimiters).

Comment: How can you deduce from $d=ax+by$ and $n=a+b$ that $a=b=0$? Certainly $a=1=b$ is a counterexample, no? Also the symmetry is that if $b\geq a$ then simply reverse the roles of $a,b$ in the proof.

Comment: @user722227 i think since n = a+b and both a an b are ≥ 0, that when n=0, then a=b=0.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn’t notice that I was missing some of the code block on my screen. So for n=0 indeed they are both 0. This case is trivial but lets you have a base case for the induction.

Comment: @user722227 that clears the induction component. If possible could you shed some light on the other queries?

Answer (score 1):

3. This is correct; observe that $a\mid 0$ so that $a$ is a common divisor of $a,0$, and further note that any divisor of $a$ and $0$ divides $a$.
4. If $a+b=n$ and $a\geq 0$, $b>0$, then $a=n-b\leq n-1$ and we apply induction hypothesis (to the pair $a-b,b$) to obtain $d=(a-b)x+by$ where $d$ is a common divisor of $a-b$ and $b$.
5. I assume you are confused about the part about $d$ being the largest common divisor of $a$ and $b$. This follows immediately from the fact that any common divisor $e$ of $a$ and $b$ divides any linear combination $ax+by$. To see this, write $a=ek$ and $b=e\ell$ to obtain $d=e(kx+\ell y)$.

Comment: That explained almost everything. But if you don’t mind me asking, can you elaborate on 4)?

Comment: @dodgevipert56 perhaps it helps to consider what the induction statement is. They prove by induction on the value of the sum $a+b$ ($a,b\geq 0$) that there is a divisor $d$ of $a$ and $b$ that is of the form $d=ax+by$.  Since they have proved the cases $a+b=0,\dots,n-1$ they can assume that there is a divisor $d$ of $a-b$ and $b$ (since $a-b+b=a<n$) such that $d$ is of the form $d=(a-b)x+by$; this is merely applying the induction hypothesis.